# What's the difference between model.attributes and JSON.stringify

Tags: backbone.js

What's the difference between `model.attributes` and `JSON.stringify` ?

Maybe some prpberties, methods do not fall ?

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({});
// We can then create our own concrete instance of a (Todo) model
// with no values at all:
var todo1 = new Todo();

// Following logs: {}
console.log(JSON.stringify(todo1));
console.log( todo1.attributes)
```

Comment: One is an object, the other converts an object to a string.

Comment: And the missing piece is : to display an object, Console.log would call stringify to generate it's display

Comment: @racraman What browser are you using?  Mine doesn't do that.  On Chrome 36

Comment: @racraman I'm not aware of any browser that does that. And given that `JSON.stringify` will call `toJSON` on things that it stringifies, it wouldn't make any sense for the console to `JSON.stringify` things it displays.

Comment: Apart from what @Daedalus already mentioned, `.attributes` is specific to Backbone where as `JSON.stringify` is a core javascript function.

Answer (score 2):

I am stealing @Daedalus's answer here but he is right, [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) returns a string representation of the model - no two ways about it.

Are you sure you don't meant [model.toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) which returns a shallow copy of attributes?

```
var artist = new Backbone.Model({
  firstName: "Wassily",
  lastName: "Kandinsky"
});

artist.set({birthday: "December 16, 1866"});

// Object {firstName: "Wassily", lastName: "Kandinsky", birthday: "December 16, 1866"} "object"
console.log(artist.attributes, typeof artist.attributes);

// Object {firstName: "Wassily", lastName: "Kandinsky", birthday: "December 16, 1866"} "object"
console.log(artist.toJSON(), typeof artist.toJSON());

// {"firstName":"Wassily","lastName":"Kandinsky","birthday":"December 16, 1866"} string
console.log(JSON.stringify(artist), typeof JSON.stringify(artist));
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/ftb83yuo/

Comment: I think it is important to note that [`JSON.stringify` will call `toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON_behavior). That's probably the root of the OP's confusion.